# session auth in python

Tags: python, session, python-requests

Using session from `requests` module in python, it seems that the session sends authorization only with first request, I can't understand why this happened.

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()
session.auth = (u'user', 'test')
session.verify = False
response = session.get(url='https://my_url/rest/api/1.0/users')
```

If I look for this response request headers I see:

```
{'Authorization': 'Basic auth_data', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.12.3'}
```

but if I send next request using the same or not url:

```
response = session.get(url='https://my_url/rest/api/1.0/users')
```

I can see that there is no auth header in request anymore:

```
print response.request.headers
{'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': '*/*', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.12.3'}
```

And I'm getting 401 response because of it.

Why is it so? Shouldn't session send auth with every request made using it?
How can I send auth data with every request using session?

Comment: You're right, it should work. Are you sure that you are not calling `session = requests.Session()` again, or otherwise resetting `session.auth`?

Comment: totaly, try run this code you see headers yourself

    `import requests
    session = requests.Session()
    session.auth = (u'x-oauth-token', 'test')
    session.verify = False
    response = session.get(url='https://test.com')
    print response.request.headers
    response = session.get(url='https://test.com')
    print response.request.headers`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I see when I run that exact code in your comment is that the `Authorization` header is missing in the *first* `print`, yet it is present in the *second*. This seems to be the opposite of the problem that you report.

This is explained by the fact that the first request is redirected by a 301 response, and the auth header is not propagated in the follow up request to the redirected location. You can see that the auth header was sent in the initial request by looking in `response.history[0].request.headers`.

The second request is not redirected because the session has kept the connection to the host open (due the the `Connection: keep-alive` header), so the auth headers appear when you `print response.request.headers`.

I doubt that you are actually using https://test.com, but probably a similar thing is happening with the server that you are using.

For testing I recommend using the very handy public test HTTP server https://httpbin.org/headers. This will return the headers received by the server in the response body. You can test redirected requests with one of the redirect URLs.

Comment: solve the problem - auth was not send because of the redirect, i change host in request to which redirect lead and session start to send auth in all requests.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find any reliable answer on how to pass, auth info while making request's session in python. So below is my finding:

```
with requests.sessions.Session() as session:
    session.auth = ("username", "password")
    
    # Make any requests here without provide auth info again
    session.get("http://www.example.com/users")
```