# Python, sending a request with headers and cookies

Tags: python, cookies, header, request, python-requests

Sending a python request to a server that requires authentication to download a file. I am trying to send both a cookie and a header with the request. What is the right format to send this request?

From chrome developer, I can see the request header as:
[image]

The python request:

```
Session = requests.Session()
cookies = browser.get_cookies()

response = Session.get(url)

tt = "ASPSESSIONIDSGSRSATR"
cookie = {tt:Session.cookies.get_dict().get(tt,""),
          cookies[2].get("name",""):cookies[2].get("value",""),
          cookies[0].get("name",""):cookies[0].get("value","")}


header = {"Host":"ecsxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
          "Connection": "keep-alive",
          "Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
          "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.89 Safari/537.36",
          "Referer":"https://ecsxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
          "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate, sdch",
          "Accept-Language":"en-US,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6"}

response = Session.get(url, cookies = cookie, headers = header)
```

Comment: Do you know the type of authentication the server uses?

Comment: No. How do I find it?

Comment: It's an Oracle EMC server if that helps

Comment: @stovfl, this is to go through a local proxy server. The question is geared towards authenticating a download from an external server.

Comment: @MalcolmMurdoch it's a kerberos sever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Comments**: ... how does that accept the username/pword?

[Using the Python Kerberos Module](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_kerberos.html)

> Kerberos Basics
>
> When setting up Kerberos authentication on a server, there are two basic modes of operation.
>   The simplest from a client implementation point of view just uses Basic Auth to pass a username and password to the server, which then checks them with the Kerberos realm.

---

> **Comments**: it's a kerberos server

There is a Optional

> [requests Kerberos/GSSAPI authentication library](https://github.com/requests/requests-kerberos)
>
> This library adds optional Kerberos/GSSAPI authentication support and supports mutual authentication.
>
> Basic GET usage:
>
> ```
> import requests
> from requests_kerberos import HTTPKerberosAuth
> r = requests.get("http://example.org", auth=HTTPKerberosAuth())
> ```

SO: [session auth in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44020439/session-auth-in-python)

Comment: I was playing with that library this morning, but how does that accept the username/pword?