# How would I rewrite this wget post statement in python 3.x?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I would like to rewrite the following statement in python.

```
wget -qO- --post-data '{"username":"foo","password":"bar"}' someUR
```

I am attempting to auth to rest api, the wget option returns as authenticated but the python that I have tried returns as "not authenticated'

I have tried using urlib and reqeusts with no success.

Here is the requests code I tried

```
import  requests
url = 'some url'

data = {
    'username': 'foo',
    'password': 'bar'
}
r = requests.post(url, data=data)
```

I have also tried

```
    r = requests.post(url, auth=('foo','bar'))
```

I have also tried

```
s = requests.Session()
s.auth = ('foo','bar')
r = s.post(url)
```

The wget option returns as expected (logged in with session data) 
Where the python code fails to authenticate

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: I think you need to use a session : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44020439/session-auth-in-python

Comment: I am attempting to auth to rest api, the wget option returns as authenticated but the python that I have tried returns as "not authenticated'

Comment: I can not see any obvious difference.  Swap out credentials for fake ones and use a free service like https://beeceptor.com to check for differences.